# Adams blue book lemma 17.14: computing a $\mathbb{F}_2$ basis for a filtration of $H\mathbb{Z}_*(bu \wedge bu)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, stable-homotopy, spectral-sequences

First off let me apologize for not being able to give all the context for this question. I'm learning how to do computations in stable homotopy theory and have been particularly spending a lot of time trying to thoroughly understand the last two chapters of Adams blue book where he computes the cooperation algebra $bu_*bu$ of the 2-primary connective complex $K$-theory spectrum $bu$.

I've had a lot of trouble understanding one part of theorem 17.14 in the blue book. This theorem attempts to show that the $s$-line of the $E_2$ page of the Adams spectral sequence for $\pi_*(bu \wedge bu)$ maps is mapped injectively by the Hurewicz map into the quotient $F_s' / F_{s + 1}'$ where $F_s' = 2^s H\mathbb{Z}_*(bu \wedge bu)$.

The particular part of Adams' proof that I'm struggling with is the computation of a $\mathbb{F}_2$ basis for the quotient $F_s'/F_{s + 1}'$. We know that a basis for the $E_2$ page of the AdSS for $\pi(bu \wedge bu)$ is given by elements of the form $\xi^{m_i}\eta^{n_i}g_i$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ where $\xi \in Ext^{1, 1}_{E(1)}(\mathbb{F}_2, \mathbb{F}_2)$ and $\eta \in Ext^{1, 3}_{E(1)}(\mathbb{F}_2, \mathbb{F}_2)$ and each $g_i$ is a generator of $\mathbb{F}_2[\xi, \eta]$.

Adams starts by taking an element $\xi^{b_i}g_i$ which sits on the $0$-line and in a $\xi$ tower above $g_i$. He takes a representative $\gamma_i \in \pi_*(bu \wedge bu)$ of the class $\xi^{b_i}g_i$ and then considers the image under the mod $2$ Hurewicz map:

\begin{align*}
    h_{\mathbb{F}_2}(\gamma_i) = 1 \otimes h_i + \cdots \in {H\mathbb{F}_2}_*(bu \wedge bu).
\end{align*}
The form of $h_{\mathbb{F}_2}(\gamma_i)$ here is given by the Kunneth theorem and the definition of graded tensor product. We omit most of the summands here since they're not important.

So now we're at the point where I'm confused. Adams states that ``by construction" the element $h_i$ above corresponds to the element $\zeta_1^{2i}$ of ${H\mathbb{F}_2}_*(bu)$. This element $\zeta_1^{2i}$ is the $i$'th basis element of the $\beta_2$ Margolis homology of ${H\mathbb{F}_2}_*(bu) \cong \mathbb{F}_2[\zeta_1^2, \zeta_2^2, \zeta_3, \zeta_4, ...]$ where $\beta_2$ is the Bockstein.

So my question is essentially why does $h_i = \zeta_1^{2i}$ hold and why is this by construction?

Note that in the original proof Adams is focused on a more general cooperation algebra $\pi_*(bu \wedge X)$ instead of $\pi_*(bu \wedge bu)$, but I only care about the case of $X = bu$ right now so that's how I presented Adams work above even though he's treating a more general case.

I apologize in advanced for the length of the question, typos and mistakes, and lack of etiquette! This is my first time posting. I'm hoping some people with more experience with this book than me can set me on the right track!

Comment: I think going back to Lemma 17.7 will gibe you an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I may be confused but it's my understanding that I would need to answer my question above in order to invoke 17.7 since the assumption for 17.7 is that the $h_i$ map to the $\mathbb{F}_p$ basis elements of the Margolis homology.